# How does censorship in the English release affect the Dragon Ball Z manga storyline?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-manga

[*Dragon Ball* Wiki](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_(manga)) stated that compared to the original Japanese manga, the [Viz English release of *Dragon Ball Z*](https://www.viz.com/read/manga/dragon-ball-z/all) is censored.

> #### English distribution
>
> [...] The "Dragon Ball Z" manga remains censored, although many volumes (prior to volume 17) are technically uncensored since they did not contain any objectionable material.
>
> - Mr. Popo's lips and other dark-skinned characters were edited because of complaints made by Carole Boston Weatherford.
> - Middle fingers were edited into fists.
>
> In 2006, Viz began releasing a second, A-rated (All Ages) edition of the series sans some nudity and profanity.
>
> - The name Mr. Satan was edited into "Hercule" (the same as Funimation's edited anime dub).
> - Firearms were edited into "laser blasters", though a pistol-armed robber was able to shoot a character without being censored.
> - Alcohol, drugs and sexual innuendo were edited.
>
> #### VIZBIG editions
>
> [...] These releases are also edited for content to make the series more family-oriented.

Does the manga alter any dialog or story? So, how bad is that in the overall experience? If it's so bad, what are my other options to read the manga?

Comment: Not sure but the title seems like it's asking for opinions. Censorship might affect manga readers' experiences differently. Might need to be reworded to something like 'how does censorship in the english release affect the dragon ball z storyline' or something similar.

Comment: There are parts that do alter the story IMHO. One of the big ones for me is that in the Anime (censored version) Goku never finds out he crushed his Grandpa when he was younger; however, in the non censored version he finds out during the Vegeta arc.. Pretty big deal to me but doesn't change major plot later.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're asking, what was cut in the English anime shows from the original story. I don't know everything, but I do know what I've seen.

Dragonball-had multiple parts cut which had Bulma either getting her top flashed(krillin vs invisible man), I believe a shower scene as well, her privates smacked(early on goku fun), and some language(not a string of curses, just an occasional bad word). Some of the dialog was altered to make it less perverted or more American/kid friendly

Dragonballz had more language cut. Like dragonball, certain phrases are altered to make it more kid friendly.

Editing-it won't ruin anything, tho some parts would be very cut thru. Watch the Japanese version, with English subtitles. Most dvds let you watch the English version with subtitles for the Japanese version, to see what's actually said.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i really was talking about the manga viz has definitely changed some art and dialog but my question here is how bad it will affect my experience

Comment: I'm interpreting this answer is about the English anime, not English manga. Considering the question is focused on the manga only, could you update/clarify the answer?